# When log size is bigger, performance is low

Tags: linux, performance, file, logging

I have multiple processes running in an embedded system, running Linux.
Each process will dump their logs to its corresponding log files,
Once the log files reach 20MB, the logs will get overwritten from Top to Bottom.

Example:

If suppose, my log has 10 line limit, after writing 10th line, it will go back to 1st line and start over writing the 1st line, 2nd line and so on.

But, the problem is if the log size is smaller, lets say 5MB, the speed is better.
If the log size is 20MB it becomes slower, the more the file size, the slower the system is.

Could someone please explain the reason behind it?

Answer (score 2):

Overwriting single lines is very slow. Because you have to rewrite *all* lines after this line, too. Say if you want to overwrite the first line in the file, all of the file's content has to be rewritten. Because you can't grow or shrink the file at random positions. This is at least true for most of the common file systems. The only exception is when every line of your log file has the same length, then you can just overwrite it without the need to grow or shrink the file.

A better concept is *log rotation*. Instead of having one 20MB file, keep two 10MB files. After the first one reaches the limit, you move it to the second file (thus throwing the second file away) and start the first file again. Then you won't have to re-write your files. Instead your are always just *appending* to the current log which is usually very fast.

Comment: Scai:I couldnt understand why all the contents of a file has to be over written. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Saran-san Because a file consists of one or multiple *blocks* of a certain size. Blocks don't correspond to lines or words or characters or anything else. When changing the content, at least the block(s) containing the content have to be rewritten. But if the content grows or shrinks, all of the following blocks are also affected because the file content is stored *continuously* over these blocks.  

Imagine a sheet of paper with a *continuously* written text. Now try to insert or remove a new word somewhere. All of the remaining content would have to move.

Comment: Scai: I think it makes sense now. Thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 main reasons to it. 
1) Software point of view (Linux Kernel)
2) Hardware point of view (Hard disk assumed)

Software point of view:
It depends on the type of filesystem in use and also how efficiently the filesystem manages disk space. Linux has something called as "buffer cache" which is used by all filesystems and every write to any of your file first goes to buffer cache and this is flushed timely by the kernel daemon. There is some upper limit to number of writable buffer blocks on cache, once it reaches the limit, it will flush them to respective drivers which inturn flush to disk..

As in your case, if for example, you are writing about 100bytes of data repeatedly and on reaching certain limit, you go back to the beginning of the file and continue this.. In this case the number of writable buffer blocks you generate over a period of time on a 20MB file is more as compared to 5MB file. And other important point is, number of disk read/write is more in case of 20MB file because kernel flushes more on the larger file as it might have more dirty blocks. But on a 5MB file, the dirty blocks although are not as much, you still may overwrite on them before kernel flushing them to disk.

Hardware point of view: 
It depends on the number of spins/drum movements that has to take place inorder to read/write your file to disk. Assuming that your linux kernel (filesystem driver) tries its best to allocate sequencial sectors on the HDD, it is possible that the 20MB file occupies sectors that are scattered across the disk while 5MB is little closely scattered esp with a heavily used HDD. This means that, if your file is 100MB, it will be way slower as compared to 20MB file.. And as you will repeatedly overwrite to the sectors that you have already written, arm spin will be more in case of 20MB file as compared to 5MB file especially as the disk access is more in 20MB case..

This is what I think will make the file read/writes slower as the size of the file grows.. And again, in the above explanation, I have not considerred multiple processes writing to multiple files.. It'll make the read/writes even slower to HDD..